# How to drop observations after a certain condition has been met in Python using pandas dataframe with more than 2 columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I am using a pandas dataframe and I want to delete observations with the same name after they met the condition (cond=1).

My dataset looks like:

```
person  med   cond
  A      a     0    
  A      b     0    
  A      a     1
  A      d     0
  A      e     0
  B      a     0 
  B      c     1
  C      e     1
  C      f     0
  D      a     0
  D      f     0
```

I want to get this:

```
person  med  cond
  A      a     0    
  A      b     0
  A      a     1    
  B      a     0 
  B      c     1    
  C      e     1
  D      a     0
  D      f     0
```

I want the code to first check if the next person has the same name, then check if the condition is met (cond=1) and if so drop all the next lines with the same name.

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `groupby` on the df and then reference the col of interest in the `lambda` and then call `reset_index(drop=True)` to remove the redundant index:

```
In [38]:
df.groupby('person').apply( lambda x: x.loc[:x['cond'].idxmax()] if len(x[x['cond']==0]) != len(x) else x).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[38]:
  person med  cond
0      A   a     0
1      A   b     0
2      A   a     1
3      B   a     0
4      B   c     1
5      C   e     1
6      D   a     0
7      D   f     0
```

Comment: No worries glad I could help